# Battery Status and Charging Notifier in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a Battery notifier in Tkinter using psutil module. I am new in **Tkinter** don't know how to solve this particular problem.

**This is my code**

```
from tkinter import *
import psutil

root = Tk()
root.title('Battery Notifier')
root.geometry('400x200')
flagBoth = IntVar()
flagBoth.set(0)

flagLow = IntVar()
flagLow.set(0)

flagCharge = IntVar()
flagCharge.set(0)

def batteryLow(percent, xoffset, yoffset):
    lowTop = Toplevel(root)
    lowTop.geometry('419x116+' + str(xoffset) + '+' + str(yoffset))
    lowTop.wm_overrideredirect(True)
    lowTop.attributes('-topmost', 'True')
    lowLabel = Label(lowTop, image=lowPercentImage, borderwidth=0).place(x=0, y=0)
    percentLabel = Label(lowTop, text=percent, font=('Sofia Pro Bold', '20'), borderwidth=0, bg='#fff')
    percentLabel.place(x=76, y=25, width=34)

    # Closing after 5 seconds
    lowTop.after(5000, func=lowTop.destroy)


def batteryCharging(percent, xoffset, yoffset):
    chargeTop = Toplevel(root)
    chargeTop.geometry('419x116+'  + str(xoffset) + '+' + str(yoffset))
    chargeTop.wm_overrideredirect(True)
    chargeTop.attributes('-topmost', 'True')
    chargeLabel = Label(chargeTop, image=batteryChargingImage, borderwidth=0).place(x=0, y=0)
    percentLabel = Label(chargeTop, text=percent, font=('Sofia Pro Bold', '20'), borderwidth=0, bg='#fff')
    percentLabel.place(x=99, y=58, width=34)

    # Closing after 7 seconds
    chargeTop.after(7000, func=chargeTop.destroy)


def batteryStatus():
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    percent = battery.percent
    chargeStatus = battery.power_plugged
    critical = 90
    if (percent < critical and not(flagLow.get())):
        batteryLow(percent, 930, 30)
        flagLow.set(1)
        if chargeStatus:
            batteryCharging(percent, 930, 150)
            flagBoth.set(1)
        
    elif (chargeStatus and flagCharge.get()):
        batteryCharging(percent, 930, 30)
        flagCharge.set(1)

    else:
        if chargeStatus == False and flagLow == 1:
            flagLow.set(0)


    root.after(1000, batteryStatus)


btn = Button(root, text='check', command=exit).pack()

lowPercentImage = PhotoImage(file='D:\\SE4\\Python\\Codes\\MiniProject\\Low Battery.png')
batteryChargingImage = PhotoImage(file='D:\\SE4\\Python\\Codes\\MiniProject\\Battery Charging.png')


root.after(1000, batteryStatus)
root.mainloop()
```

In this I am trying to get popup notification when my battery percent is lower than critical value then the popup notification will appear. If at the same time charger is connected it will show charger connected popup notification and then disappear after some time like it happens in **OS like Windows**. After that if my charger is disconnected and battery is low than critical level then again show battery low popup notification and disappear else check for battery low or charging condition if it happens then show popup notifications again.

In this problem I cannot use loops as it will make tkinter freeze. So intead I am calling the function **batteryStatus** again and again after 1 seconds. Can anyone just tell me how I can solve this particular problem. I just want a battery notifier exactly like it is in Windows when battery goes to 12% it shows notification when charger connected it disappears and when I remove charger and battery is low it again show notification.

Thanks in advance.

[This is the low notification image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzKwy.png)

[This is the battery charging notification image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjAPg.png)

[This how I want the pop notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElQcB.png) and after sometime they will disappear.

Comment: First of You could use loops if You use threading, but also what exactly is Your issue? You want to create tkinter popups that will be notifications? Or do You want those notifications to appear in tkinter window?

Comment: I don't want to use loops exactly and I want popup notifications not in tkinter window. I have included image in question how exactly it should be like.

Comment: I already gave You an answer (the loop is for presentation so You can test out how it looks) that seems to be just like You wanted (probably some adjustments can be done with multiple poups but ...)

Comment: so basically You would check the battery status every second or maybe 5 or so using `.after` and if condition is met show the popup

Comment: Yes I am checking it every 1 second and if condition is met then show popup for 5 to 7 seconds.

Comment: so what is wrong with the code then? does it work? because from what You have said it seems that everything is fine, condition is checked and a popup shows up, so what is the issue then?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something You want to do? (test run the code):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label
import time


def loop_notification(counter=0):
    if 70 > counter > 50:
        root.deiconify()
        root.overrideredirect(True)
    elif counter > 70:
        root.withdraw()
        counter = 0
    counter += 1
    root.after(100, loop_notification, counter)


root = Tk()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
root.geometry(f'400x100+{root.winfo_screenwidth() - 400}+{root.winfo_screenheight() - 100}')
root.withdraw()

Label(root, text='Notification', font='default 20 bold').pack(pady=10)
Label(root, text='Notification body here', font='default 12 normal').pack(pady=5)

loop_notification()

root.mainloop()
```

I hope You got the idea the loop can obviously be replaced with what You have and You don't necessarily need to use threads this is just as an example

The `'-topmost'` makes sure that the window is on top of others, `overrideredirect` hides the frame that is around windows

Comment: It isn't a good idea to use threading with `tkinter` as it might crash `tkinter`. Why didn't you use `.after` instead?

Comment: Also please use `threading` instead of `_thread`. Generally if a module/function starts with "`_`", it isn't meant to be used by the user.

Comment: @TheLizzard I don't know why I didn't use `.after` but now I fixed that, also what is it meant for then?  I guess I will have to learn `threading` but is it really that bad to use` _thread`?

Comment: Modules/function that start with "`_`" are meant to be part of another module. That parent module is the only that is supposed to access it like: you should use `tkinter` but you technically (it's a bad idea) you can use `_tkinter`. `threading` is simple. In this case you can just use: `threading.Thread(target=loop_notification, daemon=True).start()`. Also inside the `threading.Thead` you can pass in `args=()`. If you use `threading` you can check if the thread is still alive, and do more stuff like that

Comment: @TheLizzard Seems like `_thread` can be used by users because unlike `threading`, it is low level API, while `threading` is high level. But I don't see any reason for not using `threading` here.

Comment: @CoolCloud Usually you want to keep to the high level modules to make it easier. If you use `_thread` you can miss out things like `<threading.Thread>is_alive()`